# Converting string to java.util.date

Tags: java, string, date

I am trying to convert string in java.util.date but I am having following errors:

```
 HelloWorld.java:10: error: incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to    String                                                                                                                                                                       
        return FORMATTER.parse(date);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                              ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 HelloWorld.java:16: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Date                                                                                                                                                                       
    Date date = convertStringToDate("2015-08-03 09:19:00.000");
```

My code is below:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorld{

private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

 public static String convertStringToDate(String date) {
    if(date!=null){
        return FORMATTER.parse(date);
    }
    return null;
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    Date date = convertStringToDate("2015-08-03 09:19:00.000");
    System.out.println(date);
 }
}
```

Comment: Kindly verify my answer and confirm whether it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specified format is not matching with data format.

format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`  is NOT compatible with data `"2015-08-03 09:19:00.000"` because of two reason: (1) AM/PM is missing in date as 'hh' takes 1-12 hrs , and (2) milliseconds present in date string

Replace below mentioned line and your issue will be resolved.

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

But, none of the above mentioned issue can cause the exception you got as milliseconds is ignored by default.

Possible reasons of exception are return type of method "convertStringToDate" or `hh` having value beyond the range  between`01`  and `12`.

1. change return type from `String` to `Date`
2. Change date format `hh` to `HH`.

Comment: The milliseconds in the input string are simply ignored because [`parse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) "may not use the entire text of the given string". Actually, even the omission of AM/PM does not matter unless we call `FORMATTER.setLenient(false);` before parsing.

Comment: @MickMnemonic : thanks buddy :)  I assumed all possible cases because the code snippet  provided in question contains compile time error.

Answer (score 5):

Change your method signature into this instead:

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String date)
```

`SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns a `Date`, not a `String`.

Also, you need to handle the checked `ParseException` that the `parse` method may throw, either by declaring `throws ParseException` in the signature (and handling the exception in `main`), or by wrapping the exception into a `RuntimeException` (effectively terminating the program when bad input is given):

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String date) {
    if (date != null) {
        try {
            return FORMATTER.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // nothing we can do if the input is invalid
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Finally, you should notice that you can only parse hour values ranging from 1 to 12 with your current format (`yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`). If you'd want to parse according to the 24-hour clock, you should use the `HH` pattern for the hour part instead:

```
private static final DateFormat FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to return a `String` from your method. Change it to `Date`.

```
public static Date convertStringToDate(String date) {
    if(date!=null){
        return FORMATTER.parse(date);
    }
    return null;
}
```